# JQuery UI datepicker not working when bound to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've got this code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>date: <input type="text" name="data" class="hasDatepicker" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the input field, nothing happens. The datepicker is initialized though, when I inspect the DOM in Firebug, I get the `id="dp1260260566059"` added to my `<input>` element.

After changing the `html` and `js` to use `id` attribute instead of `class`, so having this in my code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#hasDatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

and

```
<p>date: <input type="text" name="data" id="hasDatepicker" /></p>
```

Everything works OK.

Can't datepicker from JQuery UI work for all elements of some class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please check if the datepicker works if you change the class name of the input fields from 'hasDatePicker' to something else. The reason is, when add the datepicker to the input field using the below code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#date').datepicker();
});
```

it adds the class name "hasDatePicker" to the input field. (which is the one u r using)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. This is annoying, to cause name collision this way and not be able to figure out what's wrong :)

Comment: @ sv_in the class name "hasDatePicker" did made me to struggle for more than an hour. Your answer just cleared my problem. so +1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `hasDatepicker` as your date picker's class name. Use a different name, like `date_picker`.

JQuery adds the class `hasDatepicker` to the element that datepicker() is called on. If the element already has the class `hasDatepicker`, then the datepicker() function does nothing. So, just use a different class name.