# Datepicker field to be read-only

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have an input field that takes use of `datepicker`:

```
<input id="datepicker-start_date" class="form-control text-center hasDatepicker" readonly="true" type="text">
```

and I want to make it possible for the date to be picked only by clicking (so, no input-typing). For that purpose I enabled the `readonly` property. But now the field looks as if it's disabled (gray background) and when I hover it, the selector hand is with a red-crossed (a "no-go") symbol:

[image]

So, how can I achieve an effect similar to "read-only", but not having the "disabled" hand-selector and etc.?

**Update**

The JS code:

```
    var dateToday = new Date();
    var start_date = $("#datepicker-start_date");
    start_date.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        yearRange: "-00:+01",
        minDate: dateToday,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#datepicker-arrival_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
        }
    });

    var arrival_date = $("#datepicker-arrival_date");
    arrival_date.datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        yearRange: "-00:+01"
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input id="datepicker-start_date" class="form-control text-center hasDatepicker" placeholder="When do you go?" readonly="readonly" data-parsley-required="true" name="start_date" type="text" value="2015-03-19">

<input id="datepicker-arrival_date" class="form-control text-center disabled hasDatepicker" placeholder="Arrive on...?" readonly="true" data-parsley-required="true" name="arrival_date" type="text" value="2015-03-20">
```

Comment: can u try $("#datepicker-start_date").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' ); in your document.ready method? or you can also try $("#datepicker-start_date").keypress(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});

Comment: I would advice making use of an image for the datepicker and then making your input readonly. I have tried that and it works

Comment: @Sushil - the first option gives exactly the same functionality as what I did with the HTML attribute. And the second option does not do anything...

Comment: @Pratik , could you elaborate, please?

Comment: you can also try $("#datepicker-start_date").datepicker({}).attr('readonly','readonly');

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel, please remove that tag

Comment: Your css rules are applying the cursor and background hints. You just need to override that with a new css rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/154/

This seems to be working for me. I had to remove the hasDatePicker class to make it work. Looking into why it causes the issue

```
<input id="datepicker-start_date" class="form-control text-center" type="text" readonly>
```

Give these a shot -

```
input[readonly] {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865492/jquery-ui-datepicker-not-working-when-bound-to-a-class. Did you add a hasDatePicker class yourself or was it added by JQuery?

Comment: It was added automatically.

Comment: No, it's not. :( And in jsfiddle it works even when I put back the "hasDatePicker".

Comment: Could you share your code. I wasn't working for me with that class in the input

Comment: I updated my post with the code. :) It's actually 2 fields (but same functionality, so that's why I was asking just about 1, initially).

Comment: I'm really not sure how to reproduce it, its working perfectly in the fiddle.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what I want. I know it does work as `readonly`. But visually, it has a hand-selector with a `disabled` symbol (upon hovering the field), and the field is gray. That is the effect that the "readonly" HTML attribute gives. I don't want these visual effects.

Comment: This will prevent the gray background. For the hand selector, I am not getting that in the fiddle

Comment: I think the css rule is the way to go here. However, I'd add a class to that selector to make this more restricted so it doesn't clobber all readonly inputs not associated with datepickers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(this).blur()` on click/keyup events:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/agL23e41/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker" ).click(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
$( "#datepicker" ).keyup(function(){
    //To further secure field, uncomment next line
    //$(this).val( $(this).val().slice(0,-1) );
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: Just no. This completely disables keyboard navigation for the datepicker element.